# Live stream from an IP Camera

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I want to build an application to get live video stream from an IP camera on my Tablet. I have Googled a lot but I couldn't find any practical way of doing this.
I have found this code

```
  [Activity(Label = "CameraTest1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        VideoView videoView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView1);
            button.Click += button_Click;
        }

        void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            videoView.SetVideoURI(Uri.Parse("rtsp://192.168.1.3/mjpeg"));
            videoView.SetMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            videoView.RequestFocus();
            videoView.Start();


        }
    }
```

but it gives me an error (Can't play this video)
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What error does it give you? Post the stacktrace.

Comment: the error is "Can't play this video". I am running the app on my device as my Emulator doesn't work. so Is there any way to see the trace? is there any application to take a log out of that?

Comment: View the [Android Debug Log](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log), which will hopefully contain some useful contextual info.

Comment: @jonp As I said, I don't know for some reason the Emulator doesn't work. When I want to start a device in emulator it says "Panic cannot start the device" and something like that. anyway I have to test my app on my real device for now!